# Magento add product to cart from a external file doesn't work

Tags: php, magento, cart

i have a problem with Magento's addProduct() function. I have the following code:

```
<?php
// Mage init
include_once '../app/Mage.php'; 
umask(0);  
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');     
// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();    
// Add a product with custom options
$productId = 11348;
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        528 => '1756',   // Custom option with id: 528
        527 => '1753',   // Custom option with id: 527
        526 => '1751'   // Custom option with id: 526
    )
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $request);    
// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);    
// save the cart
$cart->save();     
?>
```

It worked yesterday so include and $param are rigth but now it doesn't work. 
You also can add this product to cart inside the shop so the product exist and it's in stock.
This code doesn't seems to have any error but it doesn't add product to cart.

Thanks for help.

Comment: try to put this file in MAIN magento directory so your include_once should say 'app/Mage.php' and test it to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');    
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
$product_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$my_product_sku = 'test';        
$my_product_id  = $product_model->getIdBySku($my_product_sku);
$my_product     = $product_model->load($my_product_id);
$qty_value = 13;
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty_value));
$cart->save();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
?>
```

Comment: I think that's the same thing im doing. But i already have the product id so i dont need the sku. I also need to add custom options in my product so your code doesn't work for me. Thanks you anyway

Answer (score 0):

try with adding `form key` and `uenc` field

```
$param = array(
'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
'form_key'=>$form_key_put_here,
'uenc' =>Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('uenc', 1),
'qty' => 1,
'options' => array(
    528 => '1756',   // Custom option with id: 528
    527 => '1753',   // Custom option with id: 527
    526 => '1751'   // Custom option with id: 526
));
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work :(
Anyway i'm not sure what form key and uenc are and why they are necessary.