# Is it possible to add Product to Magento cart from another website without product being in magento store

Tags: magento, url, post, cart

I just setup a magento store (1.8) and added some demo products, but now my company wants to use the payment gateway built into magento to process payments from another website.

To explain better, my company runs a school and has a website with an application that generates bills for parents to pay. These bills vary depending on class of student and other factors. So Parent A may pay $200 while parent B pays $400.

What we want to do is post the amounts to be paid from the other website to our magento store and add it to cart for payment using our payment processor so that the magento features can still be used to log all transactions.
Since I am new to magento, I don't know if it is possible to do this and how if possible.

We intend to get the other application to generate the SKU, Product ID and Description automatically and post it together with the amount to the store.

So how do I get the magento store to receive this url and process it?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to create product in magento.

When you post the data from other site, pass the product sku.

Then load product by sku :-
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18421/why-cant-i-load-a-product-by-sku

Then check magento add to cart functionality how to add cart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264433/magento-add-product-to-cart-from-a-external-file-doesnt-work

Comment: I just got an idea and I am in the process of testing it out. I will create a php file say createnewproduct.php to receive the parameters from the url and then insert them into the magento database (thereby creating a new product). The qty of the product will be set as one such that after payment it becomes zero in the store, after creating the product the created product will then be automatically added to cart and proceed to checkout. I am of the opinion this method may work as far as my script can connect to the database and insert the values to create the product. What do you think?

Comment: Why not you can create all products into magento. So we no need to create every time. Just need to do add to cart.

Comment: In my case it is not possible to create school fees, entrance exam fees, etc as a product because the amts vary from student to student. Student A may have paid part of the tuition earlier while B is owing a full term fees. (parents also choose what books and other items to purchase and the system then sums all) The system generates a total amount based on what the student owes for the term and posts it to the magento store for payment. So it would have been easy were the amounts uniform and all fees paid at once. This is a unique system and we are trying to adapt the system to our requirement